# Create corresponding Model for JSON string to get specific value in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have an API that returns a JSON string and I want to parse that JSON string into an object.  I tried creating the object but with no luck.  Below is the sample JSON string that I want to get the value from.  Any idea as to what the class looks like in order to parse that JSON object into an object?  My main concern is to get the code which is "platinum" under currentCard.

```
    {
      "status" : {
        "currentCard" : {
          "code" : "platinum"
        },
        "status" : {
          "index" : 0,
          "value" : "This is a sample text."
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a website such as https://json2csharp.com/ or use the inbuilt tools in VS Studio (Edit->Paste Special->Paste JSON as classes) which will automatically create classes from JSON.

The above mentioned website suggests the following:

```
   public class CurrentCard
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
    }

    public class Status2
    {
        public int index { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public CurrentCard currentCard { get; set; }
        public Status status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Status status { get; set; }
    }
```

Which you can then deserialise like this:

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```